# How to ORDER BY String column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table with ID and Slot_label columns. I have different time slots in Slot Label column and I would like to order them from lowest time to highest time slot. Time slots are saved as a string values in DB. Here is how my columns look after I run this query:

```
Select *
From EVENT_SLOTS
Order By Slot_Label



ID            TIME SLOTS
1778        10:00  AM - 10:20  AM
1776        10:20  AM - 10:40  AM
1779        10:40  AM - 11:00  AM
1780        11:00  AM - 11:20  AM
1781        8:00  AM - 8:20  AM
1777        8:20  AM - 8:40  AM
1782        8:40  AM - 9:00  AM
1775        9:00  AM - 9:20  AM
1774        9:20  AM - 9:40  AM
1783        9:40  AM - 10:00  AM
```

I want my time slots to go from 8:00 am - 8:20 am all the way up to 11:00 am - 11:20 am in order. How I can get this to work since I do not have any other columns that i can order by? If any one can help please let me know.

Comment: what is your rdbms? Oracle, Postgres, MySql ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, it is Oracle.

Comment: Could you save the two times as two separate columns and then you could change it to time formatting.  Then `order by` the starting time and regular `order by` would work fine.  Example 'TimeSlotStart' = 8:00, 'TimeSlotEnd' = 8:20

Comment: I have to save them together in this case. First time I have something like this. I was wondering if SLQ has something to convert strings to numbers?

Comment: You "have to save them together"? Sounds like you maybe have to *display* them in that format, but storing them? Not so much. If you can change things, I would highly recommend you save the start and end times of the timeslots in different columns, and either have a view (pre 11g) or a virtual column (post 11g) that handles the concatenation of the two columns. Even better would be to store the start/end times as a number (eg. minutes since midnight) and then you can easily add them to a truncated date - eg. `trunc(sysdate) + 620` gives you 10:20 am today.

Comment: Again I'm working on something that have to store not just a time slots in that column, can be any string depends on the function that user pick. So for that reason I have to store them this way and also I can not create two separate tables in this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ugh, sounds horrible! Good luck with that; I've a feeling you may need it *{:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no overlap between your slots, then you can pull the first timestamp out and use that for ordering. If you need to consider both endpoints then it obviously gets more complex, but is still doable.

In my example I've left the extracted time value in the output so you can see it:

```
with dat as (
SELECT 1778 ID,        '10:00  AM - 10:20  AM' slot_label from dual union all
SELECT 1776,        '10:20  AM - 10:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1779,        '10:40  AM - 11:00  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1780,        '11:00  AM - 11:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1781,        '8:00  AM - 8:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1777,        '8:20  AM - 8:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1782,        '8:40  AM - 9:00  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1775,        '9:00  AM - 9:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1774,        '9:20  AM - 9:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1783,        '9:40  AM - 10:00  AM' from dual )
select id, slot_label, substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,'M')) first_time 
from dat 
order by to_Date(substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,'M')),'HH:MI AM');


ID,    SLOT_LABEL,             FIRST_TIME
1781,  8:00  AM - 8:20  AM,     8:00  AM
1777,  8:20  AM - 8:40  AM,     8:20  AM
1782,  8:40  AM - 9:00  AM,     8:40  AM
1775,  9:00  AM - 9:20  AM,     9:00  AM
1774,  9:20  AM - 9:40  AM,     9:20  AM
1783,  9:40  AM - 10:00  AM,    9:40  AM
1778,  10:00  AM - 10:20  AM,  10:00  AM
1776,  10:20  AM - 10:40  AM,  10:20  AM
1779,  10:40  AM - 11:00  AM,  10:40  AM
1780,  11:00  AM - 11:20  AM,  11:00  AM
```

To get the second timestamp in case you need it use:

```
    with dat as (
SELECT 1778 ID,        '10:00  AM - 10:20  AM' slot_label from dual union all
SELECT 1776,        '10:20  AM - 10:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1779,        '10:40  AM - 11:00  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1780,        '11:00  AM - 11:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1781,        '8:00  AM - 8:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1777,        '8:20  AM - 8:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1782,        '8:40  AM - 9:00  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1775,        '9:00  AM - 9:20  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1774,        '9:20  AM - 9:40  AM' from dual union all
SELECT 1783,        '9:40  AM - 10:00  AM' from dual )
select id
     , slot_label
     , substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,'M')) first_time 
     , substr(slot_label, instr(slot_label,'-')+2) last_time 
from dat 
order by to_Date(substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,'M')),'HH:MI AM')
        ,to_Date(substr(slot_label, instr(slot_label,'-')+2),'HH:MI AM')
```

To respond to your comment, yes there are lots of options available. For example you can avoid any dataype changes by extracting out the first AM/PM flag and then lpadding the first timestamp:

```
select id
     , slot_label
     , substr(slot_label, instr(slot_label,'M')-1,2) First_ampm 
     , lpad(substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,' ')-1),10,'0') first_time 
from dat 
order by substr(slot_label, instr(slot_label,'M')-1,2)
       , lpad(substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,' ')-1),10,'0');
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help with this question. I have one question, I run your code without top part(with dat as (...)) anything above Select id and I got this to work. What is the purpose of WITH dat AS ? Is it okk if I run my code without that?

Comment: The "WITH DAT AS" is just a way to create a sample data set to run the query from instead of my having to create a table, insert data, and then do the query. You can just pretend that DAT is a standin for your actual table and so ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Michael Broughton

Comment: No problem. And I will add that I agree with Boneist - if your data modeller insists on storing data this way, you're in for a bumpy ride!

Comment: I have one more question, can I use anything else instead of to_date? Is this possible to be done with CONVERT maybe?

Comment: I went with TO_DATE for the easy handling of AM/PM. Alternately, you could lpad the extracted time with 0s to ensure that 08 comes before 10 and do a simple text ordering thanks to the fact that AM comes before PM. You'd have to be careful, though, to ensure that someone doesn't slip an extra space (or drop one) between the time and the AM/PM indicator. So yes, you have lots of options. I just used to_Date because it is pretty good at doing the work of figuring out missing leading 0's or a missed space before AM/PM for me.

Comment: order by substr(slot_label, instr(slot_label,'M')-1,2) , lpad(substr(slot_label, 1, instr(slot_label,' ') -1),10,'0') for example orders first on the first AM/PM indicator, then by the first timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly i agree but something like this works :

```
with myTestCase as
(
select '8:00  PM - 8:20  PM' data from dual union all
select '10:00  AM - 10:20  AM' data from dual union all
select '10:30  AM - 10:20  AM' data from dual union all
select '8:00  AM - 8:20  AM' from dual
)
select t.*
  from myTestCase t
 order by case when instr(substr(t.data,1,9),'PM') != 0 then 12 else 0 end +
          to_number(replace(substr(t.data, 1, instr(t.data,' ') - 1),':','.'));
```

Comment: instead of all listed time slots can I use Slot_label my table column name to get this to work? My records can be different each time.

Comment: Ya sure. My post is just a proof of concept. Remove "With", Replace MyTestCase by your table name and change "data" to your column name and voilà !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was something new for me I never had anything similar to this before.